# Combining multiple streams/observables to use mapping operators

Tags: rxjs

I have 2 servers with separate streams/observables, how can I make both use the same chain so I can control them with `switchMap`, `flatMap` etc operators?

```
if (serverNumber == 1) {
  this.streamService.getStream('test 1')
    .pipe(
      map(image => console.log(image))
    ).subscribe();
}
else  {
  this.streamService.getFastStream()
    .pipe(
      map(image => console.log(image))
    ).subscribe();
}
```

For example if I fetch from server and getStream takes a while and is still in progress after getFastStream completes I want to block overwrite by the first getStream with switchMap. How can I do this? I'm new to rxjs so what I'm trying might not be how its supposed to be used.

The observable

```
  images$: Observable<string> = new Observable<string>();
```

Then do I have to push the stream onto the images$ observable with one of the operators?

```
this.images$.pipe(
  switchMap(this.streamService.getStream(1))
)
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="section">
    Click to send a request ...
</div>
<div class="section">
    <button (click)="click(1)">Server 1</button>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <button (click)="click(5)">Server 2 (Longer)</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `takeUntil` operator on the *fast* observable. Second use `merge` to take *fast* observable results until *slow* observable results start to come.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

const slow$ = this.streamService.getStream('test 1').pipe(
  map(image => console.log(image))
);

const fast$ = this.streamService.getFastStream().pipe(
  map(image => console.log(image)),
  takeUntil(slow$)
);

merge(
  fast$,
  slow$
).subscribe()
```

> Here is a [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-typescript-rxjs-playground-fast-and-slow) to demonstrate this.

Comment: I have an images$ observable, can I use it like this (not sure of syntax): images$.pipe(mergeMap(this.streamA$, ...))

Comment: `images$ = merge(this.streamA$, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

RXJS [`race`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/race) observable creator might help.

```
var server1$ = this.streamService.getStream('test 1');
var fastServer$ = this.streamService.getFastStream();

var fastest$ = race(server1$, fastServer$)
              .pipe(map(image=> console.log(image)));
fastest$.subscribe();
```

Comment: what if I need both results of the streams?

Comment: in that case, you need to separately subscribe to each stream. Something like this -
    var server1$ = this.streamService.getStream('test 1')
 .pipe(share());
    var fastServer$ = this.streamService.getFastStream()
 .pipe(share());

    server1$.subscribe(res1=>{ 
    //result from server1
    });

    fastServer$.subscribe(fastSerRes=>{ 
    //result from fastSerRes
});

var fastest$ = race(server1$, fastServer$)
              .pipe(map(image=> console.log(image)));
fastest$.subscribe();
`